# Jmeter: variable in JSON file is not changed by extracted value

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 requests: 
1) creating new publication 
2) updating it

After the first call I extract $reportId from JSON response. In second request I define a file with JSON data in 'Body Data': ${__FileToString(update_report_json_request.txt,,)} 
Inside the file I add extracted reportId:
{"sourceuri":"db://reports/${reportId}"}

But value is not being set, and content from file is sent as it is. How can I pass extracted previously value to the file used for POST data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [eval](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) function wrapping the result:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(update_report_json_request.txt,UTF-8,)})}
```

> eval function returns the result of evaluating a string expression.